# generate identical links on different devices with Branch.io

Tags: android, hyperlink, deep-linking, branch.io, deeplink

Is there any way generate identical links on different devices with Branch.io?
What I mean:
In the application I have post. I want to share this with friends. I click to share on one device and get a link
Then I want to share the same post from another device. I get the second link. They differ. But I need them to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the exact same parameters to generate the link on both the devices it should generate the same link. If even one of the parameters you add to link is specific to the user/device etc. the value you provide for the Branch link will be different and hence a new link will be generated.

Also, if you are using setIdentity() in your application each link created will be tagged with the user Identity and hence will create a different link each time.

For example:

```
final BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject = new BranchUniversalObject()
                .setCanonicalIdentifier("1234")
                .setTitle("Test for link")
                .setContentIndexingMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PUBLIC)
                .setContentDescription("Your friend has invited you to check out my app!")
                .setContentImageUrl("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Branch_Metrics_logo_color.png/1200px-Branch_Metrics_logo_color.png")
                .addContentMetadata("var1", "abc")
                .addContentMetadata("var2", "def");

LinkProperties linkProperties = new LinkProperties()
                .setChannel("App")
                .setFeature("Sharing")
                .addControlParameter("$android_deepview", "branch_default");


branchUniversalObject.generateShortUrl(this, linkProperties, new Branch.BranchLinkCreateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLinkCreate(String url, BranchError error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    Log.v("url",url);
                }
                else {
                    Log.v("url",url);
                }
            }
    });
```

The above will always generate the same link on any Android device. But is I am using `Branch.getInstance().setIdentity(user_id)` in my Android App it will generate a new link even if all the link parameters are the same.

Comment: Can i use setCanonicalIdentifier to avoid duplicated links, even some parameters are a little different ?

Comment: @cesarsicas If there is a single parameter which is different between the data provided to create a link, a new link will be generated. So if use different canonicalIdentifiers it will generate different links. But please note, The canonicalIdentifier or canonicalUrl parameter is used by Branch to identify a piece of content in your app or your website. Branch suggests that the canonicalIdentifier should be unique to that piece of content. It, in turn, helps Branch dedupe across many instances of the same thing.